# Exclude rows with consecutive data that may repeat

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table showing statuses (0 - broken, 1 - live) for a particular device at a given timestamp:

```
device_owner   device_id    timestamp          status
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:00   0    -- leave this
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:05   0    -- exclude
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:10   0    -- exclude
owner1         device_2     2001-01-01 09:15   0    -- leave this
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:30   1    
owner1         device_2     2001-01-01 09:35   0    -- exclude
owner1         device_2     2001-01-01 09:45   1
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:55   0    --leave this
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 10:10   0    --exclude
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 10:11   1
```

and so on.

I need to exclude consecutive zero statuses, and leave the one with earliest datetime. (So that I could define datetime difference between the device broken and live.)

The result:

```
device_owner   device_id    timestamp          status
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:00   0    
owner1         device_2     2001-01-01 09:15   0    
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:30   1
owner1         device_2     2001-01-01 09:45   1
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 09:55   0    
owner1         device_1     2001-01-01 10:11   1
```

and so on.

Then in my further calculations, total breakdown for *device_1* would be between 09:00 and 09:30, 09:55 and 10:11, for *device_2* – 09:15—09:45.

DDL:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
      (
          device_owner VARCHAR(10),
          device_id VARCHAR(10),
          timestamp DATETIME,
          status BIT
      );

INSERT @t ( device_owner, device_id, timestamp, status )
SELECT *
FROM   
( 
  VALUES ('owner1', 'device_1', '2001-01-01 09:00',   0),    -- leave this
         ('owner1', 'device_1', '2001-01-01 09:05',   0),    -- exclude
         ('owner1', 'device_1', '2001-01-01 09:10',   0),    -- exclude
         ('owner1', 'device_2', '2001-01-01 09:15',   0),    -- leave this
         ('owner1', 'device_1', '2001-01-01 09:30',   1),    
         ('owner1', 'device_2', '2001-01-01 09:35',   0),    -- exclude
         ('owner1', 'device_2', '2001-01-01 09:45',   1),
         ('owner1', 'device_1', '2001-01-01 09:55',   0),    --leave this
         ('owner1', 'device_1', '2001-01-01 10:10',   0),    --exclude
         ('owner1', 'device_1', '2001-01-01 10:11',   1)    
) AS x ( device_owner, device_id, timestamp, status );
```

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Gyuzal: You've been asking really good questions lately, but it's helpful to people trying to answer if you format your example data as table create and insert statements, so they can jump right in and start working on your queries. I've done it for you here. You can use this going forward if you have any other questions about writing queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be similar to a solution from Itzik Ben-Gan to [gaps and islands](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions)

```
SELECT [device_owner], [device_id],MIN(timestamp) as timestamp,status

FROM
(
SELECT *
   ,diff = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY device_owner,device_id ORDER BY timestamp ASC) 
         - ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY device_owner,device_id , status ORDER BY timestamp ASC) 
FROM @t
)A
--WhERE status = 0
GROUP BY [device_owner], [device_id],status , diff
ORDER BY timestamp
```

output of  it:

```
device_owner    device_id   timestamp           status
owner1          device_1    01/01/2001 09:00:00 False
owner1          device_2    01/01/2001 09:15:00 False
owner1          device_1    01/01/2001 09:30:00 True
owner1          device_2    01/01/2001 09:45:00 True
owner1          device_1    01/01/2001 09:55:00 False
owner1          device_1    01/01/2001 10:11:00 True
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=26d2dff50eccf1ad59c97b86d0951786)